# Loop 2 different listboxes to form one string

Tags: visual-studio, vba, loops

Program: Visual Studio 2013

Setup : Two listboxes (One has a set of Firstnames, the other of LastNames)

Example data :Firstname listbox: Michael,John,Peter
              Lastname listbox : Smith,Doe,Allen

Desired output :Michael Smith, John Doe, Peter Allen

Goal  : I need to loop through both boxes simultaneously and combine each entry in each listbox to a single string and make that information available for another function

My awfully limited approach :

```
Private Sub join_names(name As String)
    For j As Integer = 0 To LastName.Items.Count - 1

        MsgBox("NAME:" + name + LastName.Items(j))
        doSomething(name,lastName.Items(j))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MergeNames_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MergeNames.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To Firstname.Items.Count - 1
        join_names(Firstname.Items(i))
    Next
end sub
```

Now this does not produces the desired out come, but produces : Michael Smith, Michael Doe, Michael Allen cause it can't keep cycling through the loop defined in MergeNames_Click. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you are using 2 loops while I think you only need 1 to achieve this.

```
For i = 0 to FirstName.Items.Count - 1
    MsgBox("FIRST NAME: " + Firstname.Items(i) + ", LAST NAME: " + LastName.Items(i))
next i
```

Logically, isn't this all you need?

Comment: That is all what is needed indeed ! Thank you so much !